# weight transfer gives glitchy results

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to attach some pants to a character rig. I transferred the weights from my character to the pants, and it mostly works well, except two parts which stretch a TON when I animate.

[image]

I have messed around in weight paint mode, trying to tweak anything I thought might be causing this, but nothing works. It might be because I haven't done much weight painting and am just missing something really obvious, but I'm starting to feel like something else is wrong. Maybe with my mesh? (I know the normals are facing the right direction, so what more could Blender want from me? lol.)

I also tried weight painting these pants in another software, then bringing them into Blender where I retargeted the pants to the new armature. The results were almost exactly the same as above. However, in that previous software there was no such stretching. It only showed up when I retargeted the pants in Blender.

If it helps any, this is the tutorial I was following. https://youtu.be/12k1gs65tlA

Comment: The pants are baggy, and the nearest vertex or face or whatever is on the opposite leg.  Separate source mesh into left and right, separate destination mesh or mark with vertex groups, and transfer from appropriate side (with 2 data transfers for VG groups, or just different targets for separated meshes.)

Answer (score 0):

Data transfer isn't a magic bullet, for complex meshes let's say it is more of a starting point. Have you tried all the element matching methods ? I would advise using *Nearest face interpolated*, as it usually works well for two objects that are roughly the same shape, but have different vertex counts.

If you're content with what you have and just want to fix these rebellious vertices, you can select them all, then select another point on the leg to make it active (one that you think deforms correctly), head to the sidebar (N), *Item* tab, *Vertex weights* panel, and click "Copy". You may need to smooth out the weights afterwards, but it should get rid of the stretching.

Comment: Man, you're a life saver. I had tried every matching method with no success, but selecting the rebellious vertices and copying their weights to a good one worked perfectly.

Comment: For anyone experiencing the same problem, I'll detail one obstacle I had to get around. In one of the stretched areas, both legs were stretching towards each other and the stretched parts were intersecting both with each other and with the opposite leg, so it was absolutely impossible to select the proper vertices to fix. That is, until I select one pants' leg and separated it into its own object. From there, back in weight paint mode and with x-ray mode on, I used the select tool to select the troublesome vertices. Turning x-ray mode off, I selected a good vertex and copied its weight.

Comment: Rinse and repeat for the other pants leg. Once I was done, I joined the two legs back into one object.

Side note: After selecting the troublesome vertices, I tried selecting more than one good vertices to copy to to see if that would do an even better job, but I think that just garbled things up more. It looks like you should just select one good vertex. 

I still want to know why my perfectly good weight painting job got messed up as soon as I retargeted the pants to a new rig, but if you don't know that's fine.

Comment: Most likely missing bones or bone names not matching quite exactly. That means some of the corresponding vertex groups on your object would be mismatched or empty, leading to some vertices being unbound or only partially bound. Or it could be that some bones in the new rig don't have "Deform" enabled.

Comment: When copying a weight value to all selection, it does so using the value on the active vertex (in white).